# Extracting attributes from an XLIFF file using Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xliff

I am using Python to read an XML-based file, specifically the SDLXLIFF variant of an XLIFF file generated by computer-aided translation software. Such files typically contain a copy of the source file, followed by the body, which contains translation units, which usually contain "source" and "target" text. Pairs of source and target text are generally referred to as "segments". (Sample SDLXLIFF document below. This has only 3 segments, but there could be many thousands.)

The expected output is a dict of segments like `{1: ["人口は江戸末期まで概ね3000万人台で安定していたが。","At the end of the Edo period the population was stable at roughly 30 million people.","true"]}`.

For each member of the dict the key is the segment `id` attribute from the `segs-def` part of the file.

The value is a three-element list containing the source text from `<seg-source>` that has a `mid` value matching the segment id, and the target text from `<target>` that has a `mid` value matching the segment id, and the `locked` attribute from the `segs-def` part of the file.

It seems to me that it should be possible to:

1. Iterate through the segments in `segs-def`
2. Get the `id` attribute and `locked` attribute
3. Search for the source in `<seg-source>` with an `mid` that matches `id` and get the source text
4. Search for the target in `<target>` with an `mid` that matches `id` and get the target text
5. Store in the dict a list containing source text, target text and locked status as a value, using `id` as the key

[image: What to extract]

My problems are:
a) I have not succeeded in iterating through each element in `segs-def` and extracting the `id` and `locked` attributes
b) Once I have the `id`, I do not know how to search/filter the  element to find the one with the matching `mid` (for a segment id of 1, that would be `<mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">`)

So far all my code does is extract the source and target text as follows:

```
from lxml import etree
my_file = "example.sdlxliff"
f_xliff  = open(my_file, encoding='utf-8', mode='r')
xliff_input = ''.join(f_xliff.readlines())   
tree = etree.fromstring(xliff_input)

ns_map = dict()
ns_map['x'] = tree.nsmap[None]

for source, target in zip(tree.xpath('//x:seg-source//x:mrk', namespaces=ns_map), tree.xpath('//x:target//x:mrk', namespaces=ns_map)):
    print(source.text + " --- " + target.text + "\n")
```

The `seg id` and `locked` status are stored in a separate part of the file that looks like this:

```
<sdl:seg-defs>
    <sdl:seg id="1" locked="true" conf="Translated" origin="interactive">
```

What are effective and preferably pythonic ways of extracting the segment `id` and `locked` attributes from this document so that I can build the dict described above, with the `id` as the key for each segment and `locked` stored in a list with the corresponding source and target text as the value?

Sample SDLXLIFF file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns:sdl="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0"
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2" sdl:version="1.0">
    <file original="C:\Users\abc\Documents\Studio 2019\Projects\DropFiles\japan.txt" datatype="x-sdlfilterframework2" source-language="ja-JP" target-language="en-US">
        <header>
            <file-info xmlns="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0">
                <value key="SDL:FileId">02621408-34d4-4154-9dd7-7b6998ebe368</value>
                <value key="SDL:CreationDate">09/16/2023 20:30:44</value>
                <value key="SDL:OriginalFilePath">C:\Users\abc\Documents\Studio 2019\Projects\DropFiles\japan.txt</value>
                <value key="SDL:OriginalEncoding">utf-8</value>
                <value key="SDL:AutoClonedFlagSupported">True</value>
                <value key="HasUtf8Bom">False</value>
                <value key="LineBreakType">
                </value>
                <value key="ParagraphTextDirections"></value>
                <sniff-info>
                    <detected-encoding detection-level="Likely" encoding="utf-8"/>
                    <detected-source-lang detection-level="Guess" lang="ja-JP"/>
                    <props>
                        <value key="HasUtf8Bom">False</value>
                        <value key="LineBreakType">
                        </value>
                    </props>
                </sniff-info>
            </file-info>
            <sdl:filetype-info>
                <sdl:filetype-id>Plain Text v 1.0.0.0</sdl:filetype-id>
            </sdl:filetype-info>
            <tag-defs xmlns="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0">
                <tag id="0">
                    <st name="^">^</st>
                </tag>
                <tag id="1">
                    <st name="$">$</st>
                </tag>
            </tag-defs>
        </header>
        <body>
            <trans-unit translate="no" id="a8a4c497-6cd0-4b42-b87d-9f5bc8cd545e">
                <source>
                    <x id="0"/>
                </source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="ab72d223-8a2a-43b0-b503-af65b7d27de2">
                <source>人口は江戸末期まで概ね3000万人台で安定していたが。明治以降は人口急増期に入り、1967年に初めて1億人を突破した。その後出生率の低下に伴い2008年にピークを迎え、人口減少期が始まった。</source>
                <seg-source>
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">人口は江戸末期まで概ね3000万人台で安定していたが。</mrk>
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">明治以降は人口急増期に入り、1967年に初めて1億人を突破した。</mrk>
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">その後出生率の低下に伴い2008年にピークを迎え、人口減少期が始まった。</mrk>
                </seg-source>
                <target>
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">At the end of the Edo period the population was stable at roughly 30 million people.</mrk>
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">The population began growing rapidly in the Meiji Era and thereafter, exceeding 100 million people for the first time in 1967.</mrk>
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">Subsequently the birthrate began to fall, and after peaking in 2008 the population began an era decline.</mrk>
                </target>
                <sdl:seg-defs>
                    <sdl:seg id="1" locked="true" conf="Translated" origin="interactive">
                        <sdl:prev-origin origin="interactive">
                            <sdl:value key="SegmentIdentityHash">zb5f5d0tJBp6ZfAxFmVvh26SM4E=</sdl:value>
                            <sdl:value key="created_by">STONEPC\abc</sdl:value>
                            <sdl:value key="created_on">09/16/2023 19:31:48</sdl:value>
                            <sdl:value key="last_modified_by">STONEPC\abc</sdl:value>
                            <sdl:value key="modified_on">09/16/2023 19:31:48</sdl:value>
                            <sdl:value key="SDL:OriginalTranslationHash">1069896568</sdl:value>
                        </sdl:prev-origin>
                        <sdl:value key="SegmentIdentityHash">zb5f5d0tJBp6ZfAxFmVvh26SM4E=</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="created_by">STONEPC\abc</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="created_on">09/16/2023 19:31:48</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="last_modified_by">STONEPC\abc</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="modified_on">09/16/2023 19:31:48</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="SDL:OriginalTranslationHash">1069896568</sdl:value>
                    </sdl:seg>
                    <sdl:seg id="2" conf="Translated" origin="interactive">
                        <sdl:value key="SegmentIdentityHash">j8MTFYhJndu21g6nUiW8N28QU/k=</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="created_by">STONEPC\abc</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="created_on">09/16/2023 19:31:56</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="last_modified_by">STONEPC\abc</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="modified_on">09/16/2023 19:31:56</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="SDL:OriginalTranslationHash">1432236465</sdl:value>
                    </sdl:seg>
                    <sdl:seg id="3" conf="Draft" origin="interactive">
                        <sdl:value key="SegmentIdentityHash">US1BN1eE/zdK+R9JVk9NSg+LmyU=</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="created_by">STONEPC\abc</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="created_on">09/16/2023 19:32:02</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="last_modified_by">STONEPC\abc</sdl:value>
                        <sdl:value key="modified_on">09/16/2023 19:32:02</sdl:value>
                    </sdl:seg>
                </sdl:seg-defs>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit translate="no" id="acaff8f7-6e91-4012-b909-2dbe76238709">
                <source>
                    <x id="1"/>
                </source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: "desired" rather than "expected", but a delimited string like "1\t My source text \t My target text" would work as an intermediary structure.

Comment: Thanks to add this to your original post. With close to 8K, you should know ?! There's no occurrences of these strings in XML

Comment: I do actually state that I intend to create a dict, and I describe the format of the dict. That seemed and still does seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Why not giving us the expected dict ? Your question is not minimal.   
Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's been a few years since I posted and maybe expectations have changed. I will take a look and see if I can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your additional explanation:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

tree = ET.parse("example.sdlxliff")
root = tree.getroot()

ns = {'n': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2', 'm': 'http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0'}

src = {}
for mrk in root.findall(".//n:seg-source/n:mrk[@mid]", namespaces=ns):
    src[mrk.get('mid')]=mrk.text

targ = {}
for mrk in root.findall(".//n:target/n:mrk[@mid]", namespaces=ns):
    targ[mrk.get('mid')]=mrk.text

defs = {}
for seg in root.findall(".//m:seg-defs/m:seg[@id]", namespaces=ns):
    #print(seg.attrib)
    if seg.get('locked') == None:
        defs[seg.get('id')]='false'
    else:
        defs[seg.get('id')]=seg.get('locked')

dd = defaultdict(list)

for b in (src, targ, defs):
    for key, value in b.items():
        dd[key].append(value)
        
for k, v in dd.items():
    print(f'{{{k}:{v}}}')
```

Output:

```
{1:['人口は江戸末期まで概ね3000万人台で安定していたが。', 'At the end of the Edo period the population was stable at roughly 30 million people.', 'true']}
{2:['明治以降は人口急増期に入り、1967年に初めて1億人を突破した。', 'The population began growing rapidly in the Meiji Era and thereafter, exceeding 100 million people for the first time in 1967.', 'false']}
{3:['その後出生率の低下に伴い2008年にピークを迎え、人口減少期が始まった。', 'Subsequently the birthrate began to fall, and after peaking in 2008 the population began an era decline.', 'false']}
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works. In some sdlxliff files ```<seg-source>``` and ```<target>``` tags are contained within ```<group>``` tags, and these tags contain ```<g id="x">``` tags, as follows:

```<seg-source>
 <g id="2">
  <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">人口は江戸末期まで概ね3000万人台で安定していたが。</mrk>
 </g>
</seg-source>```

I have adapted your solution to capture these ```<g>``` tags as follows:
```root.findall(".//n:seg-source/n:g/n:mrk[@mid]", namespaces=ns)```
I guess the right way to tackle this would be to check for existence of ```<g>``` tags and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you search for, lxml work very similar:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("example.sdlxliff")
root = tree.getroot()
    
source = root.findall(".//{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}source")[1]
print(''.join(t.text for t in source))

target = root.findall(".//{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}mrk")
print(''.join(t.text for t in target))
   
att = root.find(".//{http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0}seg").attrib
print("ID:", att.get('id'),"locked:", att.get('locked'))
```

Source:

```
人口は江戸末期まで概ね3000万人台で安定していたが。明治以降は人口急増期に入り、1967年に初めて1億人を突破した。その後出生率の低下に伴い2008年にピークを迎え、人口減少期が始まった。
```

Target:

```
At the end of the Edo period the population was stable at roughly 30 million people.The population began growing rapidly in the Meiji Era and thereafter, exceeding 100 million people for the first time in 1967.Subsequently the birthrate began to fall, and after peaking in 2008 the population began an era decline.
```

And your searched attrib:

```
ID: 1 locked: true
```

Comment: Thank you, this is useful in that it shows me how to use xml rather than lxml, but my existing code works for extracting the source and target. The problem is extracting the corresponding  `seg id` and `locked` attributes from the `<sdl:seg-defs>` part of the file.

Comment: That gets the attributes, but they need to be the attributes that correspond to the source and target in question, so that the dict entry for the first segment is {1:["first source text","first target text","true"]} and the second is  {2:["second source text","second target text","false"]} and so on. I guess that means that  `mid="1">` in the `mrk` tag for the source and target should correspond to the segment with `id=1` in the `seg-defs` part.

Comment: In mrk tag, there is no locked and set attribute. There is a mid and mtype class only. If your question is not detailed enough, you get not the answer you need. This is what the others above written in the remarks, too.